# flutter, save data to sqlite database in assets folder

Tags: dart, flutter, sqflite

I make dogdb.db, insert 3 rows of data, save it in assets folder of flutter project and register to pubspec.yaml. Then, I run the following code and I reopen my dogdb.db I couldn't found newly added data.

1. How can I save data to dogdb.db in assets folder?
2. How can I secure sqlite database in assets folder?

   ```
   import 'dart:async';
   import 'dart:io';
   import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
   import 'package:path/path.dart';
   import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';

   void main() async {
      var databasesPath = await getDatabasesPath();
      var path = join(databasesPath, "dog.db");

      await deleteDatabase(path);


      ByteData data = await rootBundle.load(join("assets", "dogdb.db"));
      List<int> bytes = data.buffer.asUint8List(data.offsetInBytes, data.lengthInBytes);
      await new File(path).writeAsBytes(bytes);


      final database = openDatabase(
        path
       );

     Future<void> insertDog(Dog dog) async {

         final Database db = await database;

        await db.insert(
         'dogs',
          dog.toMap(),
          conflictAlgorithm: ConflictAlgorithm.replace,
        );
     }

    Future<List<Dog>> dogs() async {

       final Database db = await database;

       final List<Map<String, dynamic>> maps = await db.query('dogs');

       return List.generate(maps.length, (i) {
           return Dog(
              id: maps[i]['id'],
              name: maps[i]['name'],
              age: maps[i]['age'],
             );
           });
       }

      Future<void> updateDog(Dog dog) async {

        final db = await database;

        await db.update(
             'dogs',
             dog.toMap(),
             where: "id = ?",
             whereArgs: [dog.id],
           );
        }

        Future<void> deleteDog(int id) async {
           final db = await database;

            await db.delete(
           'dogs',
           where: "id = ?",
           whereArgs: [id],
          );
       }

        var fido = Dog(
         id: 0,
         name: 'Fido',
         age: 35,
       );

     await insertDog(fido);

     print(await dogs());

     fido = Dog(
       id: fido.id,
       name: fido.name,
       age: fido.age + 7,
     );
     await updateDog(fido);

     print(await dogs());

     await deleteDog(fido.id);

      print(await dogs());

     var dido = Dog(
         id: 4,
         name: 'Dido',
         age: 10,
        );

     await insertDog(dido);

     print(await dogs());

   }

   class Dog {
       final int id;
       final String name;
       final int age;

       Dog({this.id, this.name, this.age});

       Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
         return {
            'id': id,
            'name': name,
            'age': age,
         };
      }

      @override
      String toString() {
          return 'Dog{id: $id, name: $name, age: $age}';
          }
     }
   ```

Comment: are you deleting your dog.db with `await deleteDatabase(path);
`? If so, why?

Answer (score 0):

The [assets](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/assets-and-images#asset-bundling) folder is read-only and it's not possible to write on it. During build, the folder is bundled into an archive which the Flutter app can read during runtime.

If you'd like to secure the app's sqlite database, one way of doing this is by using [sqflite_sqlcipher](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite_sqlcipher)